# Combine 2 counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, count

Basically I have 2 selects which shows counts:

```
select count(b.i_connection_type) as Incoming_calls 
from (select i_connection 
      from Active_Calls 
      where i_connection is not NULL ) as a 
join Connections as b on a.i_connection=b.i_connection
where b.i_connection_type=2;


select count(*) as "On-Net Calls" from Active_Calls where i_connection = 1;
```

How to just stick them together, so it will be one table like:

```
|On-Net Calls| Incoming Calls|
-------------------------------
|      2     |  4            |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries return one integer each, which can be projected on a single row like:

```
select (select 1) as a, (select 2) as b;
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
```

So, simply nest the two queries in a new one:

```
select (
    select count(b.i_connection_type) from (
         select i_connection from Active_Calls 
         where i_connection is not NULL ) as a 
         join Connections as b on a.i_connection=b.i_connection 
         where b.i_connection_type=2
) as "Incoming Calls", (
     select count(*) from Active_Calls where i_connection = 1
) as "On-Net Calls";
```